# How do I ensure that custom properties of objects in a list copy to a new list in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to copy a subset of a list to a new list, but can't seem to copy over the custom class properties.

For example, below I have a House class with an int, bool, and Basement property. The Basement property is made up of a double. When I get the list of houses for the List AllHouses property, all the properties are filled. However, when I copy the AllHouses list to the SubjectHouses list (using a lambda statement to only select houses where IsSubjectHouse == true), the MLSNumber and IsSubjectHouse properties copy, but every object in the List has a null HouseBasement property.

It seems like something that should be so simple, but I've tried so many things and searched around in so many ways and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Below is a trimmed down version of the code I'm working with that hopefully gives some context to what I've written above.

```
    public class House
    {
        public int MLSNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubjectHouse { get; set; }
        public Basement HouseBasement { get; set; }
    }

    public class Basement
    {
        public double SqFt { get; set; }
    }

    public ViewSubjectHouseViewModel()
    {
        //This list has all properties
        List<House> AllHouses = GetHouseList();

        //This list does not bring over the Basement property
        List<House> SubjectHouses = AllHouses.FindAll(house => house.IsSubjectHouse == true);
    }
```

Comment: What does the comment *This list does not bring over the Basement property* means?

Comment: The code you show is definitely not enough to reproduce the problem. Read [ask] and create a [mre]. These are just some classes and a call to FindAll(), which definitely doesn't just copy properties of a value type and skips properties of reference types. What you describe is highly unlikable given the current code anyway. What also could be wrong, is that you are interpreting the results wrong. So that the data is in the source list twice, once with and once without the data you expect.

Comment: This shouldn't happen.. Are you sure your source list "AllHouses" have Basement value? Also you're not exactly copying objects here, you're just putting same objects into another list..

Comment: [Non-repro](https://www.ideone.com/a2HWA4).

Comment: Well, after working with this for so long, I figured out the issue. It's as @Noldor said, there was an error in the database that was causing the basement not to apply to the house. Sorry for the being completely off on this and thank you so much for helping me realize it. I also appreciate the clarification on the putting of the objects in the list, not copying. I feel silly getting so mixed up on this and overlooking the obvious.